# Veins V2I Omnet++ bit stream or noise

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am using Veins for V2I communication, I have already created an application and I would like to ask you if there is possible to set a background bit stream or noise in my simulation scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn't such a possibility at the moment. If you want to have background noise going on, you need to manually create transmissions to make the channel busy.

However, there are [plans](http://www.ccs-labs.org/theses/MA_ChannelLoad.pdf) to add a feature for introducing artificial channel load in the simulation in the future.